# Multiple session on server - Alamofire

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4, alamofire

I am using `Alamofire` for service call. Everything is working fine from my side. But on server side, backend people are saying that I am creating multiple session. I don't understand why it is happening.

Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: handling single session is not your task its their task ask them to return same session  on login if their exist a session if not exist create new one. Or they may expire old session when their is a valid request for another session and create a fresh one.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a variety of causes for this issue. Perhaps you're logging in a user for every network call instead of reusing a token, or perhaps you need to attach a cookie to the requests. You need to work with your backend team to see what is required to use a single session.

Comment: I am using cookie.